# Summation of SortedDictionary in C# on the basis of specified intervals of keys

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

[This is how initially value looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8tl5.png)

[After doing the sum of values based on specified interval, in this case, it summed values for keys in an interval of 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeSAi.png)

Currently, it is being done with the help of foreach on SortedDictionary but is there any other efficient way to do it, like LINQ? This will really help to optimize the code for performance issues.

Current code implementation:

```
private NewMarketPrice[] ConsolidateBids(double tickSize, IEnumerable<NewMarketPrice> bids)
    {
        SortedDictionary<double, int> consolidatedBids = 
            new SortedDictionary<double, int>(new HighestPriceComparer());

        double lowestBid = Double.MaxValue;
        foreach(NewMarketPrice bid in bids)
        {
            if(bid.Price < lowestBid)
            {
                lowestBid = bid.Price;
            }

            double consolidatedPrice = RoundDownToNearestInterval(bid.Price, tickSize);

            int consolidatedQuantity;
            if(!consolidatedBids.TryGetValue(consolidatedPrice, out consolidatedQuantity))
            {
                consolidatedQuantity = 0;
                consolidatedBids.Add(consolidatedPrice, 0);
            }

            consolidatedQuantity += bid.Qty;
            consolidatedBids[consolidatedPrice] = consolidatedQuantity;
        }
```

Comment: @mjwills, what do you recommend to optimize it as this is a financial application and getting updated values in every ms and then to provide back consolidated output to show on screen.

Comment: Your code is weird for the 'not found' scenario. You go into the `if` nd add a 0 entry, then increment it straight after. This requires an unnecessary lookup and write to the dictionary. Move the logic after the `if` into an `else` block. And `Add` `bid.Qty` rather than 0 (inside the `if`).

Comment: How long does the code take to run now? How fast do you need it ("as fast as possible" is not an acceptable answer)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can play at our end.

Comment: With these sort of questions its hard to give a direct answer in regard's to optimizations without having to ask a lot of questions or making a lot of assumptions and benchmarking to get fine-grained results.

Comment: The thing i can see in the current code is the constant dictionary lookups, where you could probably enumerate the results, groupby and sum, then project to a dictionary. To get even more fine grained, `RoundDownToNearestInterval` is an unknown quantity, likely it should be marked with the AggressiveInlining hint. What i suggest is get your trusty benchmarking software (BenchmarkDotNet) and start getting some real comparisons on your real life data

Comment: Also a SortedDictionary actually works slightly differently under the hood compared to a regular dictionary. I havent tested it, but you might be getting a huge performance hit on adds, you would need to decide whether this is actually needed

Comment: IMHO, just sort bids first, then enumerate them once to merge them.